# When I define a float input function, and call it, why is the input NoneType?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, input

Here is an example of my code:

```
def total():
 float(input("Type a number: "))

var1 = total()
var2 = total()
#etc.

decimal = 4.5783

list = [var1,var2,#etc]
for n in list:
 n += bob
```

After I write this code, I assign the variables to a list. I then add each thing in the list by decimal. However, when I run it, it is saying that I can't add floats to nonetypes. How would I fix this? Do I need to change something in the list?

Comment: You evaluate a float expression `float(input("Type a number: "))`, but forget to `return` it - just stick `return` at the start of that line and you'll get what you expect (by the way, please set your editor to use 4 space indents, it is standard for Python and will save you from many indentation errors and mistakes in the future, as well as being more readable to other people reading your code, including your future self)

Comment: Oh ok, thank you! This worked, but in the function, I added a print() after the return statement so there will be a blank line after every question but it isn't showing up.

Comment: `return` ends the function, so nothing after that executes. Put it before the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Without a return, the function will never provide a value that you can then assign to another variable. [A function is a machine that does something to input, and returns an output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVwME.png)